# Outlook going to O365 instead of Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

We've got a local Exchange server as well as an O365 subscription.  I've got a new user who upon starting Outlook is being automatically connected to O365 instead of Exchange.  I've removed his O365 link and tried setting up a new account with the Exchange option and it still selects O365 instead.  I then tried setting up a new Exchange account manually on Outlook, but it automatically points to the O365 without ever giving me manual options.  I'm unable to change the options for the account once setup too, the options simply aren't there.

For now I've got the user logging in with webmail, but I'd really like to get the Outlook client working for them.  Any ideas on how to bypass this incorrect automatic O365 setup.

Comment: Is the office365 mail account (for outlook license) the same as the exchange server mail account?

Comment: It is, and it looks like it should not be.  Ugh.  All our other users have 2 accounts but he just has one.  I can't add the correct one either as it says there's a link in place.  Looks like he was setup improperly to begin with.  So far there doesn't seem to be way to fix this without deleting all his data either.  While relatively new, he's been here long enough I don't want to wipe out all his data...

Comment: Make sure he has a fake mail address in Active Directory, and it should work. Outlook will see this mail address, try to use autodiscover for that, fail and present you with a manual setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix appears to be that you have to uninstall O365 from the machine and manually delete the Office/O365 user data folders.  Then reinstall and make sure to select manual setup when starting Outlook.  It will still automatically load (you never get a chance to override), but it will work this way.  If you let it do it automatically it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have an Office365 mail account with office suite, while the actual mail for exchange has the same domain setup.

Because you activate office365 with an account, Office365 will assume this is also where mail comes in.

Because this is not the case in your end, Go to Active Directory, and on the general tab where you can also see their name and department, fill in an email address that is incorrect.

If you now delete the outlook profile and create a new one, Outlook will see that an email address is entered in Active Directory, and try to use autodiscover for that mail account. Because it is a fake one, this process will fail and outlook will present you with a manual setup screen where you should be able to direct the server to your local exchange server.

If that is impossible, you will have to perform a migration to set him up properly.